# Why do I need two sockets in server application?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to learn socket programming in C#
By using google I found a lot of good tutorials and examples.
But here is my own code :

**Sender application :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net; // socket library
using System.Net.Sockets; // socket library

namespace Sender
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter remote IP : ");
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sender.Connect(ipAddress, 4444);
            Console.Write("Enter text to send : ");
            byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Console.ReadLine().ToString());
            sender.Send(message);
            sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sender.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();           
        } // main
    } // main
} // main
```

**Receiver application :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net; // socket library
using System.Net.Sockets; // socket library

namespace Listener
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {                        
            IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).Where(address => address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First();
            Console.WriteLine("Listening on " + ipAddress.ToString() + " : 4444");
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 4444);
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(10);            
            Socket handler = listener.Accept();
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
            int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);            
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();            
            listener.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        } // main
    } // main
} // main
```

The code works fine, but I want to know why do I need two sockets in server side? The first one is listener and the second one is handler. Is it possible to omit one of them so that the code become more simple?

By the way my code is based on these codes :

Synchronous Client Socket Example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/synchronous-client-socket-example

Synchronous Server Socket Example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/synchronous-server-socket-example

Also I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition

Comment: If the listener stays connected to that client, how will it listen for other connections?  It can only have one connection at a time...

Comment: For the record, in a datagram oriented server application (using UDP instead of TCP), the server only uses one socket. The sequence goes: create/bind/receive in a loop. There are no connections, so no need for a separate socket for each client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listener socket is listening for the incoming connections. If there were no handler socket, then there were no one to listen for parallel incoming connections until the communication with the client is over.

That's why `Accept` returns another socket, which is used for communication, and the listening socket continues waiting for incoming connections.

---

You can see it as a kind of weakly-typed objects: the Socket is responsible for both listening and communication roles, although it might be better to have different types for these two different tasks. But this behaviour reflects the [traditional socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) behaviour, so it remains as it is in order to be familiar to the people having background in network programming.

The more high-level API (`TcpListener` and `TcpClient`) makes a clear distinction between listening and communication roles.